# Swift! How to access constant in a function from another function

Tags: swift, function, constants

I'm trying to access the constance "buttonSabah" from the function "func minusBtn" to the function "@objc func buttonAddSabah".
Could you tell me how to access this constance please?
I know that I could create the constant outside the function in "class ViewController:..." but I want to know how to access this constant.

```
'import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
func plusBtn()
{
    let buttonSabah = UIButton()
    buttonSabah.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 500, width: 20, height: 20)
    buttonSabah.backgroundColor = .red
    buttonSabah.setTitle("+", for: .normal)
    buttonSabah.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAddSabah), for: .touchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(buttonSabah)
}
@objc func buttonAddSabah(sender: UIButton!)
{
    sabah += 1
    sabahLabel.text = String(sabah)
    
    if sabahLabel.text == "-"
    {
        I WANT TO ACCESS THE CONSTANC FOR A CODE HERE!!!
    }
```

This code should check the content of the constant and according that, the button should be active or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the signature to

```
@objc func buttonAddSabah(_ sender: UIButton) // never UIButton!
```

the `sender` is the button created in `plusBtn`

Comment: Many thanks for reply.
Could you also explain why not to use "!"?
I guess this will also not allow to access the constant, or?

Comment: The exclamation mark (declaration as implicit unwrapped optional) is a Swift 2 legacy for ObjC compatibility. Since Swift 3 all target/action parameters are non-optional.